# Heroku (and similar services): clone, commit and push to Git Repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I want my Rails application to commit and push git changes after the visitor entered some values on the web application.
During development I used [a Ruby Gem](https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git) to commit and push changes, which clones the repository onto the filesystem. Changes are written into those files and are committed and pushed by the Gem afterwards.

Heroku only offers a read only file system.

Is there any way to either

- commit and push files without accessing the file system?
- clone the repository into a temporary folder and commit there?
- use an other host similar to Heroku, that allows writing onto the filesystem?

Did I forget any obvious way to achieve changes on my remote git repository?

Comment: Interesting.  I've never done it, but I wonder if it would be possible to build the github api into your app-- write the changes to your github repo directly, and then use one of heroku's background task add-ons to redeploy from github when watched changes are made.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Looks like GitHub has a File CRUD API built in: https://github.com/blog/1498-file-crud-and-repository-statistics-now-available-in-the-api (for updating: http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#update-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use the Amazon cloud to solve this task.
With the 'aws-sdk' gem it is easily possible to write file changes into the S3 online space.

I then use my CIS to download the latest files and commit them to the repository, which is a simple ruby script:

```
require 'git'
require 'aws-sdk'
require 'fileutils'


folder_name = "configs"

begin
    g = Git.open(folder_name)
rescue
    puts "Cloning repo..."
    system("mkdir #{folder_name}")
    g = Git.clone("git@url...", folder_name, :path => ".")
end


g.config("user.name", "GitBot")
g.config("user.email", "...")
g.pull

FileUtils.rm_rf(Dir.glob("#{folder_name}/*"))

s3 = AWS::S3.new
bucket = s3.buckets["bucket name"] if not bucket


bucket.objects.each do |obj|
    if obj.content_length > 0
        # only files
        puts "Writing #{obj.key}"

        File.write("#{folder_name}/#{obj.key}", obj.read)
    else
        puts "Creating folder #{obj.key}"
        FileUtils.mkdir_p "#{folder_name}/#{obj.key}"
    end
end

begin
    g.add(:all => true)
    g.commit("Automatic commit from GitBot")
    g.push
    puts "Successfully pushed updates"
rescue
    puts "Nothing to commit"
end
```

It's not a perfect solution, but works great for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

I did [something similar](https://github.com/lyonrb/deploy_docus) a few years ago, which worked on heroku at the time, and should still work today.

Basically: you can actually use the filesystem, in `/tmp`.
Therefore, you have to clone in that repository and do your changes there.

However, while this is definitely possible on heroku, you're going to end up with a lot of platform specific code, which might make moving out of heroku difficult.
Using the GitHub file CRUP API as recommended in the comments seems to be a much better solution.

Comment: Thanks. I played around with the CRUP API and noticed one major problem: I don't have a local copy of the repository which results in long waiting times when accessing a file from it. What do you mean by platform specific code? Do I have to consider anything special when cloning/commiting in /tmp?